# MAC адрес в PHP для определения уникальных пользователей

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли в php определить mac адрес пользователя, который зашел на мой сайт? Если да, то скиньте, пожалуйста, код.

Это все делается для отслеживания уникальных пользователей... если использовать ip, то ничего не получится, ведь он не постоянный... возможно ли другим способом определять уникальных посетителей?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Mac адрес не является уникальным, это надо знать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Способы идентификации в интернете](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/id) - тут неплохой текст на эту тему.

Comment: Спасибо информация полезна и даже очень))

Comment: суперская статья, плюсанул )

Answer (score 5):

Запомнить компьютер(а не браузер) поможет вот эта js-библиотека: [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/)

а вот статья на русском: [Неубиваемые кукисы](http://www.inattack.ru/article/619.html)

Comment: А можно по поводу библиотек...? что-то не разглядел как ее в проект впихнуть?

Comment: на главной странице [evercookie][1] посмотрите пункт USAGE



  [1]: http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: Спасибо) я прозрел

Comment: Не знаю как она поможет.. у меня, например, все скрипты всегда запрещены для всех сайтов, кроме тех, которые мне знакомы и которыми я пользуюсь постоянно.

Comment: То есть если пол мира делают также то велика вероятность что ничего не будет работать? Жаль. В таком случае как например Контакт запоминает всех подряд? алгоритм то должен быть?

Comment: Контакт через куки сессию тречит. Если всё отрубить, то контакт не будет работать. Но он и не ставит себе цель считать головы. ИМХО 100% способа нет, хотя статистика от Panopticlick меня действительно удивила. Думаю, если статистика действительно так правдива, то это действительно способ.

Comment: 2 cy6erGn0m:
на [evercookie][1], есть пункт EXAMPLE, попробуйте.


  [1]: http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: Крайне шикарная штуковина! Этот ваш Samy Kamkar неслабо потрудился :) Только вот юзверей жалко — так срать по машинам.

Comment: по ссылке https://samy.pl/evercookie/ обнаружен троян антивирусной системой касперским

Answer (score 3):

средствами PHP это невозможно, так как мак мак адрес дальше рутера не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не возможно. Если только не попросить пользователя его ввести при входе :)

**UPD** ах да, можно ещё закинуть троянца: какой-нибудь тормозящий всё Java-апплет запихнуть на страницу, который на стороне клиента определит его mac-адрес и передаст его вам.

Comment: А каким это образом апплет получит МАК? Разве апплет может выполнять команды (читать файлы) у клиента?

Comment: Ладно... с мас адресом разобрались... а есть иной способ для отслеживания уникальных посетителей? через куки - топорно... через сессии возможно? еще варианты??

Comment: Апплет может всё читать, что захочет, если он подписан. Но для определения мак-адреса не нужно читать никакие файлы. Апплет может просматривать сетевые интерфейсы и читать их мак-адреса без всяких файлов.

Comment: извините, но тормоза с аплетом мне не нужны) нужно что-то более.... расторопное)

Answer (score 1):

WinCmd:
ping [remote IP]
arp -a

Для линукса найдешь соответственно и как запустить это с помощью php тоже.
Но скорей всего будет мак адрес оборудования провайдера.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?php
echo GetMAC();

function GetMAC(){
    ob_start();
    system('getmac');
    $Content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    return substr($Content, strpos($Content,'\\')-20, 17);
}
```